# CodeDeploy DownloadBundle : Zip end of central directory signature not found

Tags: jenkins, amazon-s3, aws-code-deploy

I am using Jenkins to start a deployment process.

```
"C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\bin\aws.exe" deploy create-deployment --application-name App.Web --deployment-config-name CodeDeployDefault.OneAtATime --deployment-group-name Development --region us-west-2 --description "App.Web" --s3-location bucket=app-artifacts,bundleType=zip,key=development/Web.zip
```

I artifact does exist on S3 and was build with Jenkins using 7zip

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a Web.zip "%WORKSPACE%\App.Web\bin\Release\Publish\*"
```

and published like this:

[image: Artifact Push]

I am getting this error:
DownloadBundle : Zip end of central directory signature not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently we are using Jenkins codedeploy plugin to do this job. [Jenkins Code deploy](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-codedeploy-plugin)
though there was an issue -file-exists-behavior. hence we have [fixed](https://github.com/softwareag/aws-codedeploy-plugin) and given [pullrequest](https://github.com/jenkinsci/aws-codedeploy-plugin/pull/19) . If you want `Added fileExistsBehavior --file-exists-behavior support` then build the [plugin](https://github.com/softwareag/aws-codedeploy-plugin).

the pipleline typically looks like below

```
step([$class: 'AWSCodeDeployPublisher', applicationName: 'App.Web', awsAccessKey: 'ERAKIAI-aws-access-key', awsSecretKey: '73I28EY7vFx-aws-secret-key', credentials: 'awsAccessKey', deploymentConfig: 'CodeDeployDefault.OneAtATime', deploymentGroupAppspec: false, deploymentGroupName: 'Development', excludes: '',fileExistsBehavior: 'OVERWRITE', iamRoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::724978192355:role/codedeploy-jenkins', includes: '**', proxyHost: '', proxyPort: 0, region: 'us-west-2', s3bucket: 'app-artifacts', s3prefix: 'app-artifacts-codedeploy', subdirectory: 'scripts/in-appspec', versionFileName: '', waitForCompletion: true])
```

In the above pipeline scripts `subdirectory: 'scripts/in-appspec'` is the codedeploy workspace. In which you will have all your `appspec.yml` and `shell scripts` are placed.

for example
[image] . The jenkins codedeploy automatically zip and upload it into s3 and then trigger the codedeploy.

If you want to add codedeploy to the jenkins freestyle job then add **Post-build Actions** `Deploy an application to AWS CodeDeploy`
[image]